# dotnet core publish: include/exclude dir in output

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

Given aspnet project with folders:

```
/
  /sql
  /WebApp
    /Client
    /wwwroot
    /Views
```

On project.json I used

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "..\\sql",
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "web.config"
    ]
  }
```

And after `dotnet publish` there was `sql`, `wwwroot` and `Views` folders.

After migration to csproj (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web), I got

```
<None Update="..\sql\**\*;wwwroot\**\*;Views\**\*">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```

After `msbuild15 /t:publish` (cli not works for me) there is `wwwroot`, `Views` AND `Client` with only `json` files inside. Files from `sql` copied but flattened.

I also try to change it to:

```
<Content Include="..\sql\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
<Content Remove="Client\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
```

and got same output.

How to remove `Client` and preserve folder structure for `sql`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Update:

When using VS 2017 >= 15.3 or a .NET CLI version >= 2.0, there is a new feature that automatically adds `Link` metadata for a few known item types (including `Content`). This can be used like:

```
<Content Include="..\sql\**" LinkBase="sql" />
```

Original:

You can use this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Client\**" />
    <Content Include="..\sql\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" Link="sql\%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The content include item's link metadata is a bit of hack to make MSBuild use the item's relative path as target path. This is because items outside of the "project cone" aren't considered in `AssignTargetPath` if they have no `Link` metadata ([source](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/6851538897f5d7b08024a6d8435bc44be5869e53/src/Tasks/AssignTargetPath.cs#L105-L107)).

Alternative to `<Content Remove="..." />` you can also do this to still have the files inside VS:

```
<Content Update="Client\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
```

Comment: this however show `sql` folder in SoultionExplorer, so I replace it with `<Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)\sql\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" ContinueOnError="false" />
` AfterTargets=Publish

Comment: You can also set `Visible="false"` on the Content Include element to hide files from solution explorer.