# ASP.NET Core 2 web deploy

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 web application. Whenever I try to deploy the application, Visual studio replaces appsettings.json and Web.config which causes problem to the application. Is there a way to inform Visual Studio that I do not want to deploy these two files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dotnet core publish: include/exclude dir in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569821/dotnet-core-publish-include-exclude-dir-in-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new ItemGroup section in the .csproj file.

For instance the following block would ensure both variants of appsettings.json are not copied to publish folder.

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Update="appsettings.Development.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
<Content Update="appsettings.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
```

Comment: No, it doesn't.