# LibCef Files not included with .net core publish

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, cefglue

I have a Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (2.1) project using

```
<PackageReference Include="Chromely.CefGlue.Winapi" Version="66.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Chromely.Core" Version="0.9.1" />
```

During build chromelycef downloads required binaries to the output folder - this is working fine.

```
(userdir)\.nuget\packages\chromely.cefglue.winapi\66.0.0\build\\chromelycef.exe download v66 --cef-binary-version=3.3359.1772.gd1df190 --cpu=x64 --dest=(outpath)\netcoreapp2.1\
```

The files are downloaded from the build controller with the build command. However I have set up a VSTS build and the publish command would not download or include the libcef files.

Is there a way to include files with the publish command other than creating a zip file from the build output?

*edit
For the moment I ended up adding a step to add files from the build output to the zip archive.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the project file to include the files you'd like to publish base on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#default-compilation-includes-in-net-core-projects).

> However, if you wish to specify, for example, some files to get
>   published with your app, you can still use the known mechanisms in
>   csproj for that (for example, the  element).

You can refer to Martin's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569821/dotnet-core-publish-include-exclude-dir-in-output) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. At the moment the downloaded files are not present in the solution folder, because they are directly downloaded to the output directory during build and this is controlled by Chromely.CefGlue.Winapi where I do not have direct control