# .NET Core include folder in publish

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have the following folder structure for my .NET Core 2.1 project:

[image]

How can I include folder `AppData` and all of its subfolders and files when I publish the solution?

I tried adding this to .csproj file but it didn't work:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="AppData\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**EDIT**

I also tried with this and it didn't work:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="AppData\**" LinkBase="AppData" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dotnet core publish: include/exclude dir in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569821/dotnet-core-publish-include-exclude-dir-in-output)

Comment: I tried with `<Content Include="AppData\**" LinkBase="AppData" />` and it didn't work.

Comment: Try: `<ItemGroup>
 <Content Include="AppData\**">
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
 </Content>
</ItemGroup>`

Comment: @Bardr It works, but only for folders which contain files/subfolders. How can I copy empty folders as well?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible but there is workaround: `<Target Name="CreateAppDataFolder" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
  <MakeDir Directories="$(PublishDir)AppData" Condition="!Exists('$(PublishDir)AppData')" />
</Target>` This will create AppData folder after publishing if it doesn't exist. It won't exist only if it's empty while publishing.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Adding this:

```
<ItemGroup> 
  <Content Include="AppData\**"> 
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
  </Content> 
</ItemGroup>
```

to your `.csproj` file will copy `AppData` folder if it's not empty. For empty `AppData` folder you can use this workaround:

```
<Target Name="CreateAppDataFolder" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
  <MakeDir Directories="$(PublishDir)AppData" Condition="!Exists('$(PublishDir)AppData')" /> 
</Target>
```

This will create `AppData` folder after publish if it won't be already included in output. Meaning this will create `AppData` folder only if it's empty while publishing.

Comment: This is the implementation I prefer since it doesn't rely on creating a placeholder file. 

With the placeholder file approach, somewhere down the road, someone may wonder why the file is there and ask what it does.

Comment: @Bardr and after you include this in the build ( when oublish ) how we are going to retrieve the files inside the folder? I`ve tried many ways but i keep getting errors that the folder cannot be found... In the build action, i set the files to contents

Comment: I'm publishing to linux-x64, single file, self-contained, application.  The Target command in the .csproj files doesn't get executed. I've tried both MakeDir and Message commands.  Nothing.  VS 2022, NET 8.

Answer (score 28):

There is simple and useful solution:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="AppData\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

You can find more tricks here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj

Comment: You can also add LinkBase="MyDirectory" to the <Content> element if you want to specify a folder to place the files into within the publish directory.

Comment: Link is dead :(

Answer (score 9):

First solution, if run dotnet build or dotnet publish will add the folder inside bin.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="AppData\**"  CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"  />
</ItemGroup>
```

Second solution, if run dotnet publish will add the folder inside bin.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="AppData\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 6):

None of the above solutions worked for me. So, I took the same approach taken in "React project template" and I added this code to my .csproj file:

```
  <Target Name="PublishFrontend" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="ClientApp\build\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work for me when running a build in Azure DevOps. Was this solution only for a local publish?

Comment: I didn't build in Azure, but it works in my CI. I use AppVeyor.

Answer (score 4):

You can put a placeholder file in it (or use your existing files). Then add the file to the project and set the file properties: Copy To Output Directory: Copy if newer or Copy always.

Other way: add a post build step command, that creates the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put 'logs' directory into publish out directory, finally this lines into Project.csproj works (mind to set 'Delete existing files = false' in publish setting):

```
<Target Name="LogDirectoryOnPublish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
    <RemoveDir Condition="Exists('$(PublishUrl)')" Directories="$(PublishUrl)" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(PublishUrl)\logs\" />
</Target>
```