# ASP.NET Core - Not able to read static HTML file using C# StreamReader inside Controller

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a asp.net core project with angular template with below files structure.

[image]

I want to read the static HTML file (**EmailConfirmation.html**) from Template folder.

My code to read this file inside a controller as below.

```
string body = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("./Template/EmailConfirmation.html"))
{
body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

But when I publish this app to azure, There is no folder created with the name **Template** inside **wwwroot** folder. Thus  caught with an error

> Something went wrong: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not
>   find a part of the path
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Template\EmailConfirmation.html'

For your note : I have tried with steps mentioned in the below article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2

But not worked out !

How can I solve this problem. Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Comment: You need to include the file in your project file for the build to copy it to your output folder.

Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762744/net-core-include-folder-in-publish

Comment: Drop your `Template` folder into the `wwwroot` folder instead and it should work fine from there or configure as per tutorial.

Comment: I tried same. But not worked.

Answer (score 3):

Stratup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
     app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
     {
        FileProvider = new 
        PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Templete")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/Templete")
     });
}
```

Controller Action

```
string body = string.Empty;
//using streamreader for reading my htmltemplate   
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine("Templetes", "EmailConfirmation.html")))
{
   body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(Path.Combine(@"./templates", $"{templateFileName}.html")))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```