# .netcore Filestreamresult is throwing 500 internal server error on pivotal cloudfoundry

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, filestream, cloud-foundry

**Filestreamresult is resulting in 500 internal server error on Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF)**. When I run angular app on localhost and .netcore webapi on localhost I am able to download the file but on cloudfoundry it does not work.

I have researched and found some solutions but none worked in my case. I have tried following links 
https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/125221/asp-net-core-sending-a-generated-pdf-directly-to-browser
https://weblogs.thinktecture.com/pawel/2017/03/aspnet-core-webapi-performance.html

- I have tried returning `File(mstrm,"text/plain")` works on localhost
  but not on PCF.
- I have also tried `File(mStrm, "application/octet-stream")` works on
  localhost but not on PCF.
- My other API endpoints work on PCF, just this one is causing the
  error.
- Also checked logs on PCF but it only shows that it resulted in 500
  error.
- This api is using dotnet_core_buildpack and is hosted on cflinux.

  public FileStreamResult appConfigure([FromBody] Test test)
      {

  ```
      var testFile = _test.generateScript(test);
      MemoryStream mStrm = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testFile));
      mStrm.Position = 0;
      return new FileStreamResult(mStrm, "text/plain")
      {
          FileDownloadName = test.testName + ".txt"
      };
  }
  ```

result should be test.txt file returned with http 200 response. But I am receiving 500 error 
POST https://testapp.apps.pcf.testapp.com/api/test/genscript 500 (Internal Server Error)

Have been stuck on this for last 2 days, any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: ++exception message please. Guessing and fortune telling sucks

Comment: Thanks Tseng, Actually this code is working. I need to work on PCF error logging in my application. But the error message is Cannot find the File at location /template/ TestSctiptTemplate.txt. Locally it is able to find it  but on PCF it is not finding it. Do you know how can i route to that file on PCF ?

Comment: Then thats your error. Missing folder, uncomplete deployment? Do you include that folder when publishing your application? Is it created inside the publishing artifacts? Did you try adding a dummy file to that folder and have it added to publishing? GitHub / deployments sometimes don't publish empty folders

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54765877/455493) answer shows how to add folders to the publishing output (via `<Content .../>` tag in csproj

Comment: `/template/` isn't going to exist in your container and you cannot write to that location on CF. Your app runs as a non-root user, so you don't have permissions to that location. You need to put your templates somewhere where the user running your app does have permissions. The easiest location would be under $HOME or $PWD (both happen to point to the same place), so `$HOME/templates` or `$PWD/templates` which would be a `templates/` directory under the root of the application files you push.