# ASP.NET Core Web API & Entity Framework Core: physical storage not working on production server

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API where an endpoint uploads a PDF file. The current method to upload to physical storage (the hard disk) is this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload([FromForm] UploadModel uploadModel)
{
    var fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath,
                                          "uploads", 
                                          uploadModel.ImeiOrSerial + "" + uploadModel.EquipmentInvoice.FileName);

    await uploadModel.EquipmentInvoice.CopyToAsync(
            new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

    using (var context = _context)
    {
         var equipment = new Equipment();

         equipment.TypeOfEquipment = uploadModel.TypeOfEquipment;
         equipment.EquipmentBrand = uploadModel.EquipmentBrand;
         equipment.ModelOrReference = uploadModel.ModelOrReference;
         equipment.ImeiOrSerial = uploadModel.ImeiOrSerial;

         equipment.Path = uploadModel.ImeiOrSerial + "" + uploadModel.EquipmentInvoice.FileName;

         _context.Equipment.Add(equipment);

         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

         return Ok(await _context.Equipment.FindAsync(equipment.IdEquipment));
     }
}
```

If I do this in development, everything works perfectly, I get the name of the PDF invoice and it gets in the uploads file inside the solution directory

[image]

[image]

But if try to do this on my IIS web server, it doesn't work.

I enabled swagger in production mode to see what error the swagger was throwing, but I only get this:

[image]

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

I wrap my post method in a try catch and now it shows me the following error:

[image]

Comment: DirectoryNotFoundException ?

Answer (score 1):

Ady's comment is correct. By default, the `uploads` will not included in publish. You need enable it in your .csproj file. You can check the doc about [Visual Studio publish profiles (.pubxml) for ASP.NET Core app deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

You can add below code to your .csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup> 
  <Content Include="uploads\**"> 
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
  </Content> 
</ItemGroup>
```

[image]

[image]

If your `uploads` folder is empty, you can create a simple txt file in it or [use `MakeDir` to create it when publish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54765877/7687666).

Comment: I didn't were able to find the .csproj file that you mention, however I get to solve my problem in another way.

Comment: @Smuk [Check this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wukOQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found that work for me, do the following:

Go to the IIS manager.

Right click on your backend page, in my case its called API:

[image]

Then go to Edit Permissions:

[image]

Select the option that says IIS_IUSRS, like shown in the previous image, then click in the edit button.

Pick again the option that says IIS_IUSRS and give permission to full control and modify.

Finally go to the wwwroot folder where you published your API and create a new folder where its gonna be located all the files. In my case I named the file "uploads"

[image]

And that's it, you should be able to upload files, and locate them in physical storage

Comment: `Finally go to the wwwroot folder where you published your API and create a new folder` ???

Comment: It's not the solution for this issue. Next time when you deploy the project(new version), you will know it.

Comment: Yeah I kwno I will have to create again the same folder each time, besides all the files will desapear, but It was the temporary solution, I still dont know the correct answer.