# .Net core bower_components folder missing in wwwroot directory

Tags: azure-web-app-service, bower, asp.net-core-3.1

I have fresh .Net core web app and it's source code uploaded first time on production server with CICD of the same. It went successfully but when I run the web app, the UI and js files were missing. After much digging in, I found that bower_component folder is missing which includes necessary css and js files from wwwroot folder.

Can anybody tell me why it is not uploading bower_components to the wwwroot folder?

Comment: Aside, you mention that this is a fresh ASP.NET Core web application, but also that it's using Bower. You should know that [Bower is deprecated](https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/). You should instead prefer using e.g. Yarn with WebPack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `.csproj` file to include `bower_component` folder.

You can read offical document first([Include files at publish time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-5.0#include-files)), then you can refer below posts.

Related posts(include files, not folder) can refer to:

[1. Unable to find files located in my root project folder when hosted on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279143/unable-to-find-files-located-in-my-root-project-folder-when-hosted-on-azure/62295252#62295252)

[2. .NET Core include folder in publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762744/net-core-include-folder-in-publish)

[3. How to copy a folder to output directory and keep its root folder? #2949](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2949)

[4. dotnet core publish: include/exclude dir in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569821/dotnet-core-publish-include-exclude-dir-in-output)