# How to deploy the entire project to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, web-deployment, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application from Visual Studio to IIS Web Server (on VPS). But all my `Areas` folders, Cshtml files, view components etc, have not been published - only the `wwwroot` folder and its contents have been uploaded to the server. I saw about `project.json`, but .NET 5 doesn't use it anymore.

PS: when I try publishing clicking directly from the "Area" folder selected, the files are published, but the .Cs files are published too.

How can I fix it?

On publishing to Microsoft Azure, everything goes fine. But to my VPS it is not working as I would like to.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is open scm site, check the publish file under `D:/home/site/wwwroot`. And compare the structure of deployed file between azure and IIS. It should be same.

After the comparison, see if the folders or files are not included. Just modify it in the `.csproj` file.

**Related posts:**

[1. Unable to find files located in my root project folder when hosted on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279143/unable-to-find-files-located-in-my-root-project-folder-when-hosted-on-azure)

[2. dotnet core publish: include/exclude dir in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569821/dotnet-core-publish-include-exclude-dir-in-output)